# MariaDB: Can not insert data into table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am try to execute the next query:

```
INSERT INTO `migrations`(`id`, `migration`, `batch`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3])
```

and get the error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '[value-1],[value-2],[value-3])' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB `INSERT INTO` statement demand to use `quotes` for you values:

```
INSERT INTO `migrations`(`id`, `migration`, `batch`) 
VALUES ('value-1','value-2','value-3');
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=35834b79e7213d64d119afc2bae759d6&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)